# Android simple ArrayAdapter from String[]

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

i can write simple array adapter from class structure, but now i want to write simple array adapter from String, in my application i have simple array as :

```
private String[]  panelNumbers;
panelNumbers = G.getActiveUserInfo().phoneNumbers.split(",");
```

for show this array into Listview, array items merged with RadioButton, my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkMark="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="xcgdf"
        android:textColor="@color/black_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_divider"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

now i want to fill this array items by custom array adapter my ArrayAdapter dont correct

My ArrayAdapter

```
public class AdapterSmsPanelNumbers extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {

    public AdapterSlideMenuSMS(String[] array) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.call_list, array);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(array[position]);
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private final TextView    text;
        private final RadioButton radio;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            radio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**
i can not fill listview items by single String[], i dont want to create class from panelNumbers,please help me to resolve this class problems to have simple ArrayAdapter showing simple Array

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: change `ArrayAdapter<String>` and `holder.text.setText(getItem(position));`

Comment: @Sergey Glotov i can not fill list view items from single String[] array

Comment: @Sergey Glotov my post updated, please review that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Adapter` concept has to be understood first.
It needs an array (or list) of objects so for each item it will find inside it, it will generate a `View` (when needed).

Here, if you want to play with an array of `String`, you must tell to the `ArrayAdapter` that it will handle `String`s, with :

```
public class AdapterSmsPanelNumbers extends ArrayAdapter<String>
```

The `ArrayAdapter` already has a mechanic to handle these `String`s you will give him. A method make it easy to get an item in the provided array :

```
String stringAtPosition = getItem(position);
```

So, as @SorryForMyEnglish suggested:

```
public class AdapterSmsPanelNumbers extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public AdapterSlideMenuSMS(Context context, String[] array) {
        super(context, 0, array);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_choice, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getItem(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private final TextView    text;
        private final RadioButton radio;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            radio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `Activity`, you can use this custom `ArrayAdapter` :

```
private String[]  panelNumbers;
panelNumbers = G.getActiveUserInfo().phoneNumbers.split(",");

ArrayAdapter adapter = new AdapterSmsPanelNumbers(this, panelNumbers);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who see the question and just want to know how to create an array adapter from a programmatically created list of strings instead of a string resource, you just need to do

```
String[] myStringArray = (String[]) myArrayListOfStrings.toArray();
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.my_layout, myStringArray);
```